# .htaccess php Rewrite view.php?visopslag=(id)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have to rewrite `www.url.com/opslag/view.php?visopslag=(id)` with htaccess to something more beautiful :o) Im creating a forum likely application. This is what i want to be rewrote: 
My request is:

```
www.url.com/opslag/vis/id
```

How can I do this? I've tried lots of different things like:

```
RewriteRule ^/opslag/([^/\.]+)/?$ view.php?vis=$1 [L]
```

My complete .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On  
"#Rewrite view.php?vis=id  
RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/([0-9]+)$ /opslag/view.php?vis=$1 [L,R,QSA]  

"#Remove index.php  
"#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/    
"#RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]  

"#Remove /page/      
"#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
"#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
"#RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is `id` always numeric, alphanumeric, etc? What can it include?

Comment: Only numeric.. Like 1,2,42,100,1.. Always a number.. Like in Stackoverflows url: url.com/questions/123123/ like that one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make a backup of your `.htaccess` file. Now remove all lines -- make it empty (there is too much noise there at the moment).

Add these lines to your empty .htaccess (should be in the root folder of your website):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/(\d+)$ /opslag/view.php?vis=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This should treat `www.url.com/opslag/vis/11` as `www.url.com/opslag/view.php?vis=11`.

Please ensure that you have no more `.htaccess` files in `opslag` folder.

Comment: This one works @LazyOne :o) Now I just got one problem, I need the other rewrites too. The one to remove /page/ because im using a CMS and I wanna remove index.php with the 3rd rule. How do I do this?

Comment: Good start. Show me the URL that you currently have (the one that you just mentioned) and the URL how it should look after redirect/rewrite

Comment: Ok, I need to remove www.url.com/**page**/ 
My links are: href='/$rows[link]'

Comment: Before I used this: #Remove /page/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

Comment: @LazyOne Dude, the 2 other RewriteRule's works perfectly together with the one you'd created for me. Everything works perfectly right now. Thanks for you help. And @Michael thanks to you 2! :o)

Comment: @Kolind Sorry, I do not understand this. I need **real** (like we did before) URL examples (from => to) so that I can undestand what needs to be done & build the Rewrite Rule.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've provided so far, I offer this.  If you give a little more information, I will amend it accordingly.

```
RewriteBase /somedir
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/([0-9]+)$ /opslag/view.php?vis=$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe I should tell you that, my htaccess file is in the root, and the files view.php is in a subfolder. Does this have anything to do with?

Comment: Try adding the `RewriteBase` as above.  Also add the `[R]` flag (`[L,R,QSA]`) temporarily to see what it's attempting to redirect to.

Comment: @Kolind Remove the RewriteBase then. Also try removing the `^` from before `^opslag`.

Comment: @Michael okay I got this now: 
RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/([0-9]+)$ view.php?vis=$1 [L,QSA,R] 
and that doesnt work

Comment: Tried to remove the ^ and that doesnt work. do I have to add /opslag to view.php? like this: 
RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/([0-9]+)$ /opslag/view.php?vis=$1 [L,QSA,R]

Comment: @Kolind Oh yes, you probably do need `/opslag/view.php?`

Comment: Then it's never matching to begin with.  Further up this comment chain you have `opslag/vis/` which is different than in your question `opslag/visopslag/` Which is it supposed to be?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, Michael. It has to be opslag/vis/

Comment: Im having this one right now: RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/([0-9]+)$ view.php?vis=$1 [L,QSA] and nothing happens at all.

Comment: Please post your directory structure with your original question.

Comment: Ok, in my index.php file, I have to show some threads, and their title can be clicked with the href="/opslag/vis/<?=$rows[id]?>".. 
My directory structure is: index.php -> opslag -> view.php
And I want the link to be: www.url.com/opslag/vis/id right now it's: www.url.com/opslag/view.php?id=(id)

Comment: My complete htaccess is: ´RewriteEngine on

#Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#Remove /page/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

#Remove /opslag/
RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/?$ /opslag/view.php?vis=$1 [L]´

Comment: @Kolind you need to add the rest of the .htaccess as an edit to your question above. Can't read it down here.

Comment: @Kolind comment out everything else in .htaccess.  Then move the opslag rule to the top , right after `RewriteEngine On`.  Looks like both of the first two rules are preventing it from being reached.

Comment: And make your opslag rule look like mine in the answer above.

Comment: @Michael Ok, I've commented out, everything else, and moved it to the top.  My .htaccess is:  RewriteEngine on  
#Remove /opslag/  
RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/([0-9]+)$ view.php?vis=$1 [L,QSA]  and my links are: /opslag/vis/<?=$rows[id]?>  and nothing works.

Comment: My htacces is: RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/([0-9]+)$ /opslag/view.php?visopslag=$1 [L,QSA]  Still doesnt work..

Comment: @Kolind change it again according to my example. I had a typo and added the [R] flag to see where it's actually going.

Comment: @Michael Doesn't work. I's my links correct? /opslag/vis/(id)

Comment: @Michael I get no errors or anything like that. It's like it doesn't even match the links or something like that.

Comment: @Kolind I'm sorry, I don't think I can troubleshoot this further.

Comment: @Michael Hm, I just don't get why: RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L] works and: RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/?$ /opslag/view.php?vis=$1 [L] doesn't :(

Comment: @Kolind: Move the rule done by @Michael ( `RewriteRule ^opslag/vis/([0-9]+)$ /opslag/view.php?vis=$1 [L,R,QSA]` ) to the top, just below `RewriteEngine on` line and try again: `http://www.yourdomain.com/opslag/vis/123`

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for picking this up.  I have too much work to complete to keep up with it.

Comment: @Kolind Please update your question with the current content of .htaccess. Thnx

Comment: @LazyOne What should my LINKS be like?

Comment: @LazyOne Hello Lazy, I've edited my question with my current .htaccess

Comment: @Kilind Does such URL work for you: `www.url.com/opslag/view.php?visopslag=123` ? How do you want this URL to look like instead? Like this: `www.url.com/opslag/vis/123`? Thnx

Comment: @LazyOne - this url works: www.url.com/opslag/view.php?vis=11. I want it to be www.url.com/opslag/vis/11. I've already edited the question. THanks for trying to help me

Comment: @LazyOne When I try to use www.url.com/opslag/vis/11 it says: Not found, the requested url doesn't exist on the server

Comment: @Kolind I will post it as a new answer and will will go trough it one by one if necessary.

Comment: @LazyOne Let's do that. That's easier :)