# how to remove question mark from two php URLs in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove question mark from two URLs like this:

URL 1

```
http://localhost:8888/events/event.php?id=222
```

to

```
http://localhost:8888/events/event/222
```

URL 2

```
http://localhost:8888/membership/register.php?id=162
```

to

```
http://localhost:8888/membership/register/162
```

i'm use this code in .htaccess and just the 'event' page work:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /events/event(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /events/event/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^events/event/([^.]+?)/?$ events/event.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /membership/register(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /membership/register/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^membership/register/([^.]+?)/?$ membership/register.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess php Rewrite view.php?visopslag=(id)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416292/htaccess-php-rewrite-view-phpvisopslag-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /events/event(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /events/event/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /membership/register(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /membership/register/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# rewrite from pretty URL
RewriteRule ^events/event/([^.]+?)/?$ events/event.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^membership/register/([^.]+?)/?$ membership/register.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

# Rewrite with .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```