# How to URL Slug without id?

Tags: php

I've been thinking about how does people make a special link like

```
www.domain.com/this-is-a-link
```

then i checked how to make a slug URL and it was good, But i was wondering, Do i make a special column for `SLUG URL` inside the database and call the entire row using the `SLUG` instead of the `id`? Is that how all people do it? Or is there a better way?

```
[id    title    content    slug]
[1   TheTitle  LoremIpus  the-title]

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE slug = $slug";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess php Rewrite view.php?visopslag=(id)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416292/htaccess-php-rewrite-view-phpvisopslag-id)

Comment: I know about the rewriting, But my question is about Does people rewrite using `$_GET` and special column for the `slug`? or does they call the `id` then call the `title` and use slug function? like `www.domain.com?slug=the-title` and then fetch it using this `$_GET` or they go using id only `www.domain.com?id=1` and transform from id to title?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `URL rewriting`. Please search on that topic. You will find articles like [These](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/), which has information about the URL rewriting!

Comment: I know, But what i mean is Do i have to create a column for the `slug` then rewrite it? then i call & mention the post page using `$_GET` using the `slug`, Like instead of using id.